# Sharing data between multiple UWP apps across multiple users

Tags: c#, uwp

I am working on a family of UWP applications where all the applications need to share approximately 9GB of data among themselves, across all users. This data should be accessible to only my applications and not generally across the system (i.e. public directories are not an option).

Currently, I am able to share data among all the applications using Publisher Cache directories, but that only allows files to be shared across a multiple applications for a single user. Installations of the same applications on other user accounts will have their own Publisher Cache Directories. Is there a location or a configuration where I can save data such that only my apps have access to it, but it is shared by those same apps across multiple user accounts on the same computer?
As far as I can tell, UWP apps are severely limited in what folders they are allowed to read/write to.

Comment: Is this data in the form of a database, or records that could be in a database, or is it separate files?

Comment: It's mixed between a database, and a few hundred thousand images and videos.

Comment: So, could it all live in a password protected/encrypted database, that is in a public directory?

Comment: I use my internet host to hold images and a database, for which I wrote little XML access wrappers to send queries to the server via https and retrieve data back via https responses. Then I can use UWP, WInForms, WPF or whatever to access my data and images. This provides protected access on any network with internet access, with any PC that has my application. It is just a bit slower for large queries.

Comment: We looked into using web services for storing much of this data. Unfortunately, one of the constraints is that the data must be accessible on a completely disconnected device.

Answer (score 0):

> Sharing data between multiple UWP apps across multiple users

UWP has the same installation path and different sandbox path for different user. you could package the data into appx. But your data is too large.

> We looked into using web services for storing much of this data. Unfortunately, one of the constraints is that the data must be accessible on a completely disconnected device.

For your requirement, you could deploy web service in the local that could be accessed with the app for different user.